# ClassLoader.getResources() works inside module-path, fails inside jlink

Tags: java, resources, jlink

In the following testcase, we execute `ClassLoader.getResources()` on the module path. When running outside `jlink`, the method returns one entry. When running inside `jlink` the method returns zero entries. Is this a JDK bug?

You can download the testcase from GitHub: https://github.com/cowwoc/jlink-testcase/

Alternatively, you can recreate it by hand:

src/main/java/module-info.java

```
module jlink.testcase {
    opens database.migration;
}
```

src/main/java/testcase/Main.java

```
package testcase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<URL> resources = Collections.list(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResources("database/migration"));
        System.out.println("Found: " + resources);
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/database/migration/V1__placeholder.sql (empty file)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jlink-testcase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>20</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <mainClass>testcase.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

good.bat

```
@echo off
java -ea --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jmods;target\jlink-testcase-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" --module jlink.testcase
```

bad.bat

```
@echo off

rd /s /q target\jlink
set JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=-ea
jlink --add-modules jlink.testcase --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jmods;target\jlink-testcase-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" --output target\jlink --launcher testcase=jlink.testcase
target\jlink\bin\java --module-path target\jlink-resources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --module jlink.testcase
```

Comment: Loading of directories is not supported for any Class.getResource* or ClassLoader.getResource* method.  The fact that it happened to work in one case does not mean it is behavior you can rely on.  The correct way to do this is to hard-code the list of known files, or generate a listing at build time and include the list file as another resource in your application.

Comment: @VGR Is this documented anywhere? Many tools, such as Flyway, use a classpath-driven plugin mechanism. How would they replace something like this? https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations.html#discovery

Comment: You can use plugins.  In fact Java SE has its own class for that, java.util.ServiceLoader.  Finding resources on the classpath is fine.  Trying to list a *directory* of resources is not fine and should not be attempted.  I have never found documentation that outright forbids directories as resource paths, but it should be noted that most classpath entries are .jars, which have “directory entries” which are not actually listable directories, just zero-length archive entries whose names end with a slash. No getResource* method’s documentation specifies what content is returned for those entries.

Comment: Beware of third-party libraries that claim to list directories in a classpath. They usually rely on the assumption that every classpath entry is a local .jar file. But there’s a reason ClassLoader and URLClassLoader are separate classes—ClassLoaders do not have to make use of .jar files! Any library which assumes otherwise will eventually break when used with advanced class loaders—a current example being all the tools that depended on tools.jar in the JDK, which was never a guaranteed feature and now no longer exists. ‘Happens to work’ is not the same as ’guaranteed to work.’

Comment: @VGR The mechanism uncovered by ClassGraph looks bulletproof to me. The API explicitly covers listing all resources in a directory: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleReader.html#list()

Comment: That method doesn’t actually list a single directory;  it lists every resource and class file in the module, much like JarFile.stream() does.  You can use a filter to restrict the Stream to entries in a certain directory, which I suppose will work reliably, though it seems a bit inefficient since you have to skip over all the entries which aren’t in the desired directory.

Answer (score 0):

While it is still not clear why `ClassLoader.getResources(String)` behaves different inside `jlink` and out, ClassGraph provides a [mechanism](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/Classpath-Specification-Mechanisms) that works inside jlink as well.